# Change a filename

Tags: php, file-rename

I want to change the name of a file. The source filename is changing all the time. The produced name mus be fixed. Here is mij script:

```
<?php
$directory = '/public_html/Weercam/FI9853EP_00626EA2E6A9/snap/';
foreach (glob($directory."*.jpg") as $filename) {
    $file = realpath($filename);
    rename($file, str_replace(".jpg","test.gif",$file));
}
?>
```

It works. BUT the name shoud be only test.gif. Now it makes the name like: abcdefghtest.gif

I tried to use the script on the server. It works fine, onle the outcoming name is wrong

Comment: Is the file actually a GIF file? If not, then you should convert it into an actual GIF, if that is the format you want. Just renaming it won't convert it.

Answer (score 0):

str_replace only replaces part of the string, leaving the rest. Maybe you're looking for `rename($file, "test.gif");`

Comment: what would the script look like? What should I leave away then?

Answer (score 0):

you want to use the rename function in a different way in this case:

```
rename($file, "test.gif");
```

syntax:

```
rename(oldname, newname, context)
```

context is an optional parameter which specifies the behavior of the stream .

Comment: Delano jpg file has an ever changing name. So how should I correct it then. Thanks for your answer

Comment: the file name may change,
because you made a var for the filename.